# window.open() URL having www. and cookie issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, popup

I have a script that does this:

```
window.open("http://www.myurl.com","myURL","width=400,height=200");
```

okay, this works. I have cookies set and sessions set. User can only access my page when they login. When I logout, this page will direct me to a login page from `window.open()` as predicted.

When I take out `www` in the `window.open()`

```
window.open("http://myurl.com","myURL","width=400,height=200");
```

the cookies and sessions doesn't apply? I can still go into the page even if I've logged out.

Now when I tried `myurl.com` in the original browser, it directs me to my login page where its supposed to.

Any ideas why? I mean I can just set it to www, but I would like to know what the reason is?

Thanks

Comment: Your cookies only apply to the `www` scope. You can define the scope when you set the cookies, and usually, you would set it to `http://*.myurl.com` so that it applies to all subdomains.

Comment: I've set my cookies to "/" = `setcookies("name","value",$time,"/")` this doesn't apply to subdomains?

Comment: I'd guess that would only apply to your current subdomain (so if it was set in `http://www.myurl.com` then it would only apply to such).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're setting your cookies using PHP's `setcookie()` function (as that's what you commented on your question).

PHP will set these cookies to the domain the user is currently on. If the user is on `www.mysite.com`, the cookie will be applied to `www.`-subdomain only. You should instead give the domain PHP should set the cookie for:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', $time, '/', '.example.com')
```

Note the leading dot: `.example.com`, as it represents a wildcard so that the cookie is applied on all subdomains of `example.com` (that is, `www.example.com` and `example.com`, as well as other subdomains you might have).

For more information on this function: [PHP docs](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)